# File permission denied

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm testing my app on a galaxy S5 with API 22, and a Nexus 6P with API 25. My app is compiled with 23.

I'm trying to read images from an obb file as:

```
Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(obbPath+"img1.jpg"));
```

When I run on my Nexus 6P there is no issue, however with the galaxy S5 it gives the error:

```
01-18 14:42:36.007 14032-14032/com.nick.app E/BitmapFactory: 
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/mnt/obb/8a0cd43307e4b1f6568009da3580d11f/img1.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

In my android manifest I have declared the permissions as below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

This error confuses me that it is on the older device and not the newer with the new runtime permissions which I have *not* implemented. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough rebooting the device was enough to solve the issue for me. Didn't think to do that at first but it has worked now. This issue seems odd to me but is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> My app is compiled with 23.

It does not matter what is your `compileSdk`, however it matters what is set as your `targetSdk`. If this is `23` or higher, then your manifest permissions does not matter if you run your app on Android 6.0 or newer as in this case you **must** support runtime permissions as [documented here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

There are some libs that can simplify the task of implementing runtime permissions, but if you really do not need any of API23+ features in your app you should be able to simply lower `targetSdk` to i.e. `22` and then have your manifest permissions honored on any platform.

Comment: My `targetSdkVersion` is set to 21